# How to force free CSS resize on input element when its width is specified?

Tags: html, css

I have simple problem - text input element which has specified 2 CSS attributes, see code below:

```html
<input type="text" style="resize:horizontal; width:200px" />
```

When only `resize` attribute is specified, the `input` can be resized to any width. However, if I have `width` specified, the `input` element can be resized only wider than `200px`, not shorter.

Is there a way how can I have default width specified and in the same time have input element resizable to any width? Wider or shorter than set by `width` attribute?

Thanks for any help in advance!

EDIT - clarification: I need input element to be resizable freely - to any width - more than `200px` and less than `200px`

EDIT 2 - I am preferably looking for pure CSS solution if it is possible.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is pretty close to workable. You need to set `size="1"` as an attribute on the `<input>` to resize really small. The resize is controlled by `input:active` which overrides the base class with `width: auto;`. `input:focus` prevents it from shrinking when you tab into it to type.

Potential issues: `input:focus` forces the `<input>` to a specific `min-size`, which might be larger than what it's been resized to. You could `min-width: 100%` to make this a "feature" instead of an issue, giving the user more space to type. If the `<input>` has focus, resize is still limited by `min-width`, but resize is usually done post-focus (and also, mostly used to make something larger).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/jNnCW/

HTML (with styles inline as you requested):

```html
<input id="text" type="text" size="1"/>
<style>
    input {
        resize: horizontal;
        width: 200px;
    }

    input:active {
        width: auto;   
    }

    input:focus {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: I like your solution the most. But I have just one small glitch - I need to specify width of the text input element INLINE. I can't use "input { width:200px }" declaration in stylesheet, because this value is dynamically generated for each input of the form by PHP. Could you please update your answer so it works with inline style declaration ? I've tried fixing your fiddle, but it didn't work out: http://jsfiddle.net/fvUSb/

Comment: Can you add a `<style>` inline? You could put your classes right next to your `<input>` instead of in a stylesheet.

Comment: doesn't work, please fix your demo

Answer (score 13):

[Here is an example](http://jsfiddle.net/drq0nz6j/) of using div with flexbox & contenteditable=true instead of input. Only CSS + HTML. I found it useful if no tag 'form' required.

```css
#flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  line-height: 30px;
}
#inner {
    padding: 0 20px;
    min-width: 100px;
    height:auto;
    line-height:1.5;
    outline:none;
    background-color: #dfd4d7;
}
```

```html
<div id="flex">Type some text here:
<div id="inner" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false"><div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything I read online (see below) indicates that the `resize` property only works on block level elements that **do not** have `overflow: visible` set and on `textarea` elements. It does not even technically work for `input` elements (which are neither, and even if set to `display: block` I could not get the `resize` to be recognized by Firefox).

Links: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/resize and http://www.css3.info/preview/resize/ and http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui/#resize

Answer (score -1):

The simple way to make an `input` resize freely is to set it to it to have `width: 100%`, and then place it inside an `inline-block` container with a `min-width` (`min-width` sets the default width for the `input`). Resize the container to resize the `input`.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/TvZAr/

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer has negative votes, doing exactly this led to a couple of stubborn inputs shrinking to fit