# How to resize input field

Tags: css, input, resize, field

I'm trying to make my input field resizable, but the code I found doesn't work anymore.

```
#mededeling 
{
resize: both;
}
```

Does anybody know the most recent working code?

Comment: It is a textfield
<label for="mededeling">Mededeling: </label>
              <input type="text"
                 id="mededeling" />

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642255/how-to-force-free-css-resize-on-input-element-when-its-width-is-specified

Comment: Sorry, I mean textarea `<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>`

Answer (score 1):

what about using textarea instead of input? 1row height textarea looks just like input type[text] and can be submitted in form:

```
textarea name="" id="" cols="30" rows="1"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
    input {
        resize: horizontal;
        width: 200px;
    }

    input:active {
        width: auto;   
    }

    input:focus {
        min-width: 200px;
    }
</style>
```